# What is the rule in cricket if the wicket keeper steps forward and catches a ball before it crosses the stump / batsman?

Tags: rules, cricket

What is the rule in cricket if the wicket keeper steps forward and catches a ball (ie before the bowl ends).
(1) before it crosses the stump, 
(2) before it crosses the batsman?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is covered by [Law 40.3 Position of the wicket-keeper](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-40-the-wicket-keeper/):

> The wicket-keeper shall remain wholly behind the wicket at the striker’s end from the moment the ball comes into play until
>
> (a) a ball delivered by the bowler,
>
> either (i) touches the bat or person of the striker,
>
> or (ii) passes the wicket at the striker’s end,
>
> or (b) the striker attempts a run.
>
> In the event of the wicket-keeper contravening this Law, the striker’s end umpire shall call and signal No ball as soon as applicable after the delivery of the ball.

Therefore both your cases would be a no ball, unless the batsman has played the ball (or it has hit their person).